# On Bootstrap v5.3: Need help understanding navbar bg-dark" and data-bs-theme="dark"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

On this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/

If you scroll down to "Color schemes"

```
 <nav class="navbar bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
   <!-- Navbar content -->
 </nav>
```

1. What is the difference bg-dark and data-bs-theme="dark"?

If you scroll down to "External content"

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

2. How come the data-bs-theme="dark" is eliminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they write in the paragraph above code you posted:

> New dark navbars in v5.3.0 — We’ve deprecated .navbar-dark in favor of
> the new data-bs-theme="dark". Add data-bs-theme="dark" to the .navbar
> to enable a component-specific color mode. Learn more about our color
> modes.

Also `data-bs-theme` is for using different color schemes. Not just light or dark, you can define your own. See more in [Color modes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/) documentation.

Comment: @ Marek, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.


     I understand that  Bootstrap deprecated .navbar-dark and uses data-bs-theme="dark"


     Then under "Color schemes" section (Right below the yellow box)  it reads: "Navbar themes are easier than ever thanks to Bootstrap’s combination of Sass and CSS variables. The default is our “light navbar” for use with light background colors, but you can also apply .navbar-dark for dark background colors. Then, customize with .bg-* utilities."


I did not realize that section was under v5.2. So that's why I was confused.